# How to check whether data is empty or not in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have to check whether there is file downloaded or blank inside @empqua.document.
My code is like.

Related Document: `<% if @empqua.document.empty? %> Blank <%else%>
<%= link_to "Download",@empqua.document.url, :target => "_blank", :class => "filelink" %>
<% end %></td></tr>`

I write this code But it gives an error:

> undefined method `empty?' for /documents/original/missing.png:Paperclip::Attachment

Comment: use @empqua.document.nil?  instead of   @empqua.document.empty?

Comment: I got it It works when i use present? instead of empty.                   <tr><td> Related Document: <% if @empqua.document.present? %> <%= link_to "Download",@empqua.document.url, :target => "_blank", :class => "filelink" %> <%else%>Empty<% end %></td></tr>

Comment: @empqua.document.exists?

Comment: or .blank? or unless xxx.nil?

Answer (score 0):

try it with

```
@empqua.document.present?
```